# copy and paste legend with plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

how can I copy and paste legend with the graph from Mathematica 10.0 to Word. i can copy and paste a graph from Mathematica to word, but legend does not get copied. how do I copy paste the legend ?

Comment: Just drag your mouse over both the legend and the plot until both are selected and copy and past as usual. Or click the plot and then shift click the legend.

Comment: Or *Rasterize* the whole thing and same as Sjoerd's from then on.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: That doesn't work for me, whether pasting into Word or Gmail.  (Mathematica 11.3.0.0 on Mac with Chrome.)  The plot+legend is only mouse-selectable with blue highlighting, and hence only pastes raw Mathematica code rather than an image.  (On the other, if I click on the plot, I get orange-box-highlighting, and this will correctly paste the plot image in other applications, but without a legend.)  This question should be re-opened.  If there's no way to copy-paste a graph with legend using the mouse, the answer should include that fact.

Comment: @JessRiedel I don’t have a Mac so it may be different for you but for me selecting both plot and legend and then going to the Edit menu and copying as bitmap works.

Comment: That works, but at much lower resolution compared to clicking on the plot, getting orange-box highlighting, and then copy-pasting.  I really think this question (albeit sloppily written) brings up a useful issue.  I can easily imagine a great answer that describes what's going on under the hood with the clipboard and the difference between blue-background highlighting, orange-box highlighting, and the save-as menu. (Also, shift-clicking the legend definitely doesn't work for me on Mac.)

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -3, 3},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotLabel -> "This is my plot"]
```

Then from the Edit pulldown menu:

```
Edit > CopyAs > PDF
```

Then paste into your *Word* document.

[image]

Comment: This works! thanks!